# AWS Cognito - preAuthentication and customMessage triggers

Tags: amazon-cognito

AFAIK, a cognito sign-in attempt will fire 2 triggers, namely **pre authentication** and **custom message** as [per documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-identity-pools-working-with-aws-lambda-triggers.html).

Anyone know what triggers comes in first? or if they we can rely, that they will be executed in sequence?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some experiment to confirm the behavior and i got this result:

```
2019-12-05T23:58:23.663Z - preAuthentication
2019-12-05T23:58:24.102Z - customMessage[authentication]

2019-12-06T00:00:02.366Z - preAuthentication
2019-12-06T00:00:02.957Z - customMessage[authentication]

2019-12-06T00:03:40.013Z - preAuthentication
2019-12-06T00:03:40.467Z - customMessage[authentication]

2019-12-06T00:07:32.168Z - preAuthentication
2019-12-06T00:07:32.692Z - customMessage[authentication]
```

So it seems like **preAuthentication** always comes first!

Answer (score 0):

CustomMessage triggers occurs in specific cases, for example:

- SignUp;
- AdminCreateUser;
- ResendCode;
- ForgotPassword;
- UpdateUserAttribute;
- VerifyUserAttribute;
- Authentication.

Whenever some of these events occur and has a trigger configured, the trigger will be fired. Pre-Authentication on the other side will occur each time a user authenticate himself.

If you have a custom message trigger and the user tries to SignUp that trigger will be fired. After the SignUp each time the user authenticate himself the auth trigger will be fired. So the answer is: depends on your authentication flow.

Comment: thanks for your answer. sorry the custom message it quite vague. what I specifically mean for custom message, is authentication. So customMessage[authentication] and Pre Authentication triggers - will both fire